# Adding file to SVN source control > add grayed out in XCode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I have SVN set up on a server and have pushed the Xcode project onto the server. SVN has been working for committing changes made to a file or multiple files back to the Source Controlled copy. However I am unable to add new files (such as when creating a new View Controller or adding an image for example) to SVN. They exist just locally and I cannot figure out a way to get them into source control.

I tried committing the file and receive this message:

[image]

I have also tried right-clicking the file, source control > Add. But that option is grayed out:

[image]

Is there something wrong with the SVN setup or with the way I have checked out the repository? Committing changes to an already existing file works just fine.

Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is setup to use Git now. If you can switch to git you'll be a much happier camper.

use git init, git add . from command prompt first and use gitignore to add the xcuserdata file to the ignore list. Once you do a commit -m "Initial" from the command prompt you should be able to start committing from Xcode.